# How to tell the Yii framework to add a header x-request-id to each request?

Tags: php, yii, middleware

I want to basically add a Request ID to my Yii application so that I can track requests that come from other services and figure out errors that are linked across them.

I want to add an `x-request-id` header, either extracting it from the incoming requests, or generating a new one if the request did not include one. Then, I want to print this in case of any errors. I see that the error messages in the `/runtime/logs/app-errors.log` contain some fields like `action`, `action-path`, `message`, so this seems like a good place to put my `request-id`.

Now, I am basically a newcomer and I don't really know how to assemble the pieces to do this. I could just research all the Yii documentation but it make take a week, only to learn that the solution is just 10 lines of code at the right place.

So, my question for someone more familiar with Yii would be: What would be the outline of such a task? I see something called Behaviours, would these be what I need? I could try to figure out the details myself, but I am not sure what exactly to touch here.

Sorry if my question is too vague!

Comment: As a quick update, I went into `modules/logger/log` and extended the Target classes that I use which have a `getMessagePrefix` method, and with this I was able to add the request ID that I can obtain from `Yii::$app->getRequest()->getHeaders()->get("x-request-id");`. I see in my app.logs and app-errors.log, i get the request ID if it exists. Next step is gonna be trying to figure out how to create one if it doesn't exist (I'm assuming this shouldn't be part of the Logger logic)